# Burning a CD-R Query

Tags: cd-burning, cd-r

Sorry I have a few questions.

1. If a CD-R already had either a jpeg or audio track on it would it then ask for the CD-R to be named when using it or is naming it only available if it is a blank CD-R being used for the first time?
2. If a CD-R has JPEG’s and audio tracks on it will it still play in a regular CD player?
3. If a CD-R had jpegs on it already but in a different session I wanted to then add audio tracks is this possible or do you have to add everything at the same time?
4. Can you delete files from a CD-R?

Comment: Generally, SE likes one question per question, but as these are closely related, I've answered below. As there's not much detail in the question, the answer's a bit hand-wavy too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most of this is reliant on the CD player. Computers will see data partitions, regular music players won't - some will be able to find an audio partition, others will only find it if it's the first thing on the disc.
A lot of this is very hand-wavy, because your actual circumstances are unclear.
Check the manual for your player , burner & burning software for more detail.

1. Audio CDs don't have names, or indeed any metadata. Only the data partition can be named, so it depends how the first session was burned.
2. Depends on the player, see above.
3. It depends on whether the session was closed/finalised after the last recording.
4. No, you need CD-RW to do that.

As mentioned in comments, [CD-Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-Text) allows the specification of track name metadata for players that support it, including some car players. This would need to be provided for in the burner software too.

Comment: [CD-Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-Text) allows the specification of track name metadata for players that support it. I've seen it available in many car cd players.

Comment: @Mokubai - I hadn't thought of that - have to admit my last in-car CD player was in the late 90's, early 2k's, it's been iPod since they were first released.

Comment: For multi-session data-CDRs you CAN delete files from previous sessions. Because the directory gets written in every session and only the one from the latest session is used when reading the CDR.

Comment: ... which techncly. isn't "deletion", just refraining from inclusion in the file and directory structure. Depending on the software used for "burning" the (R, record once) CD/DVD you could actually "move" a file, by simply recreating the file/folder structure, making it point into the previous DATA. Once DATA is written, it cannot be removed, just excluded from the content listing (i.e. files in folders), a NEW content list can be written. *(Please note; CD and DVD was years ago, I have no idea how it has developed since. A USB-stick is "R&W" & at least 16x larger, that's where I am today).*

Comment: @Hannu - I have similar qualification to make… checking back my records I see the last CD/DVD I burned was in 2006 ;) I still have them all, from 96 - 06… but some of them don't read so well these days. I've moved the important stuff to HD & online since.

Comment: Hmm... I need to check those DVD-R's... ;-)

Comment: @Hannu - sooner rather than later. I had to use Toast in 'try your best, dammit' mode to image one of them recently, burned 2000. If I had the energy to plod through the whole lot, I could squeeze them in a corner of a spare hard drive these days… it's going to be under 100GB in total for three big cases of disks, but it's hard to be bothered for the number of times I've ever actually needed anything off them in the past decade. ;)

Comment: ;-) I have a box full of Amiga 3.5" diskettes... unknown status (and yes; Computer and matching monitor too).